# How to use the pre-processor directive #include in a multi-file arduino c project?

Tags: c-preprocessor, arduino-c++

I've wrote some code but when it's in a single file I find the code overwhelming and so I've tried to seperate the code into 3 files. The first being the main section (SACode.c), the second for making a char/string dictionary (CharCharStarArray.h) and the last for storing constants (constants.h). The SACode needs to be able to access CharCharStarArray.h and constants.h. and so I've used the following code in SAcode.c

```
/* File CharCharStarArray.h*/
#ifndef CharCharStarArray.h
#include "CharCharStarArray.h"


/* File constants.h*/
#ifndef constants.h
#include "constants.h"


//more code

#endif
#endif
```

The header file CharCharStarArray.h also needs to access the constants.h file and so in the CharCharStarArray.h file I've included this snippet

```
#ifndef constants.h
#include "constants.h"

//more code

#endif
```

When compiled I get "redefinition" or "previously defined here" errors from the constants.h file

I've commented out the include constants code in the SAcode file and it compiles but this seems like bad practice. If I didn't include the CharCharStarArray.h file then SACode.c wouldn't be able to access the constants file

Here's a recreation of the problem

headefiles

```
#ifndef header1.h
#include "header1.h"

#ifndef header2.h
#include "header2.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

/*header2*/
#endif

/*header1*/
#endif
```

header1.h

```
#ifndef header2.h
#include "header2.h"

int header1var = 5;

#endif
```

header2.h

```
int header2var = 3;
```

Comment: First line: `#ifndef XXX`. Second line: `#define XXX`. Last line: `#endif`. All the rest in between the second line and the last line.

Comment: And `XXX` doesn't need to be the same as the file name (in fact, I'm not sure you're even allowed to use a `.` in there).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb I've done that but I still have the same errors and it does compile with the `.`

Comment: Not sure what exactly it is that you're doing, but you should generally use `#ifndef` clauses mostly in your header files only (and not in your source files, in an attempt to include or to not include your header files, as seems to be the case in the code that you've posted).

Comment: And I don't see `#define XXX` anywhere in your code, so make sure you follow the instructions above precisely.